# bounce turtle from green patches in netlogo world

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to implement a bounce turtle logic. When any turtle move towards green patches, I want to set `turtles head = set head ( - head)`

My code is:

```
ask turtles [ask turtles [
  ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 2 !=[move]  
[ set heading ( - heading) ]
```

Question: but it gives error ( OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle or patch but got NOBODY instead).
How to solve this error?

Comment: if you have `ask turtles [ ask turtles [...] ]` you are asking the code to go through all the turtles individually and have them ask all the turtles to do something. So if you have 20 turtles, then each one will do the something 20 times.

Comment: Did you intend `set heading (- heading)` to turn the turtle around so it faces the other way? That code doesn't do that, rather it reflects the turtle's heading across the y axis. if you want to turn around, `rt 180` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a number of typos in your code sample, but the answer to your immediate question is that if the patch that would be ahead 2 lies outside the world, `patch-ahead 2` will return `nobody`, as there is no such patch. So, when you get `nobody`, your turtle is very close to the edge of the world.  I assume you would want to turn around in that instance as well, so your `ifelse` might look something like

```
ifelse (patch-ahead 2 != nobody and [pcolor] of patch-ahead 2 != green)
  [move]
  [set heading (- heading)]
```

Note that you need to check for `nobody` **before** checking for the color.